# mat table column with filter the sort arrows is not visible

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-filters, angular-material-table

I am new to angular... 
My mat-table is working fine, but when column has filter and sorting functionality the sort arrows is not visible on columns with filter.
I was trying to adjust the column wight, but no matter how small or big the column the arrows is not visible.
There is sample project that reproduce my issue.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hbakxo-sdjyya?file=app%2Ftable-filtering-example.ts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will only be visible for the column width greater than mat form field

and for reducing the width of form field use exact size not %. percentage doesn't change sort header width

```
.mat-form-field {
    font-size: 13px;
    width: 110px; //put the value you need
  }
```

here is the [slackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hbakxo-2frpys?file=app/table-filtering-example.ts) edit of your link.

Answer (score 0):

setting your column width got it to display

```
.mat-column-position {
 width: 25%;
}
```

Comment: doesn't work for me .. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hbakxo-sdjyya?file=app%2Ftable-filtering-example.css

Comment: are you wanting the sort arrow to display by default?

Comment: yes, all columns need to have sort by default, the problem is with 2 first columns that have filter.